# Regular expression to parse ffmpeg info

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Here is my code:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3456':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1809.522000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 256
    Metadata:
      service_name    : AIR_CH_521_6M
      service_provider: ITE
    Stream #0:0[0x7d1]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x7d2]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels
```

How do I get the fps,pixel format,Video Codec, Audio Codec, Input Resolution, Output Resolution and Audio Channels as an array from this string?

Based on my efforts so far, this is as far as I could get as I'm not a regex expert :

```
/Video: ([^\r\n]*), ([^,]*), ([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4})/iu
```

Edit: I tried for another video and the regex didn't match. Any idea why?

```
 data :ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv

data :  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

data :Metadata:
  Server                NGINX
  width                 1280.00
  height                720.00
  displayWidth          1280.00

data :  displayHeight         720.00
  duration              0.00
  framerate             30.00
  fps                   30.00
  videodatarate         0.00
  videocodecid          7.00
  audiodatarate         125.00
  audiocodecid          10.00

data :Input #0, live_flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/test/test':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX
    displayWidth    : 1280

data :    displayHeight   : 720
    fps             : 30
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 11168.744000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mpegts, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 720
    fps             : 30
    profile         :
    level           :
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

data :frame=   54 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     825kB time=00:00:02.22 bitrate=3031.6kbits/s
data :frame=   66 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=    1004kB time=00:00:02.74 bitrate=3002.7kbits/s
data :frame=   82 fps= 50 q=-1.0 size=    1224kB time=00:00:03.34 bitrate=2998.5kbits/s
```

Here's input from another file for the same command for which the regex doesn't match : https://regex101.com/r/Vyq5kD/4

Comment: Can you provide the output that you want ?

Comment: It would be great if we could get an output like this  .. INPUT [h264,High,yuv420p,1280x720,SAR 1:1,DAR 16:9,30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc ].  [aac,LC,44100 Hz,stereo,fltp,128 kb/s] , OUTPUT [h264,High,yuv420p,1280x720,SAR 1:1,DAR 16:9,30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc ].  [aac,LC,44100 Hz,stereo,fltp,128 kb/s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you can simply design some expression similar to,

```
video:\s*([a-z0-9]+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*\((\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)\s*\/\s*[0-9]+x[a-z0-9]+\)\s*,\s*[a-z0-9]+\(([^)]*)\)\s*,\s*([0-9]+x[0-9]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s+([a-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s*([a-z]+)\s*,\s*(\d+[a-z]*)\s*([a-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s*([a-z]+)
```

#### [Demo for Video](https://regex101.com/r/HWKCW5/1/)

or

```
audio:\s*([a-z0-9]+)\s*\((\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)\s*\/\s*[0-9]+x[a-z0-9]+\)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s*([a-z]+)
```

#### [Demo for Audio](https://regex101.com/r/Ox0zV7/1/)

and extract/capture what you wish to, and you might want to most likely change the boundaries, based on the inputs that you might have.

#### [Demo for Combination](https://regex101.com/r/zJMqW8/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HWKCW5/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/HWKCW5/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

```js
const regex = /video:\s*([a-z0-9]+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*(\((\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)(\[\d+\]\s*)\s*\/\s*[0-9]+x[a-z0-9]+\)\s*)?,\s*[a-z0-9]+\(([^)]*)\)\s*,\s*([0-9]+x[0-9]+)(\s*\[[^\]]*\])?,([^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*),?([^,\r\n]*)?/gmi;
const str = `    Stream #0:0[0x7d1]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x7d2]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mpegts, to '/dev/null':

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo 2 for video](https://regex101.com/r/f8IOiQ/1/)

#### [Demo 2 for audio](https://regex101.com/r/LqwwN5/1/)

#### [Demo 2 for Audio/Video Alternation](https://regex101.com/r/uwOLzz/1/)

---

Another way is to just simply target what you like to capture, maybe one be one with simpler expressions such as,

```
(\d+)\s*fps
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/bHb2nM/1/)

---

#### Design:

- Anything that you'd like to capture you would include in a capturing group `()`, such as [`[a-z0-9]+` for `yuv420p` which would become `([a-z0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/jtUnwp/1/).
- We would pick the longest string input and we incorporate everything in that, then for any other strings with missing values, we would add a `?` at the end of those missing values in the expression to make it optional.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do you know how I can further split these values h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive) into ['h264','Constrained Baseline'],['yuv420p',progressive'],['mp3','0 channels'] ?

Comment: Its not matching when I run the same command for another source video.  Please see updated here https://regex101.com/r/zJMqW8/2

Comment: your latest regex is working great but it's retrieving the first instance it finds. Can we make it retrieve the same data for every occurrence of  stream# ?

Comment: I used the generate javascript option on regex101 and it provides me the output i need but it provides the output for the first occurence of stream#. Heres it's output..ound match, group 0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 1k tbc
Found match, group 1: h264
Found match, group 2: High
Found match, group 8: progressive
Found match, group 9: 1280x720
Found match, group 10:  [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]
Found match, group 11:  q=2-31
Found match, group 12:  30 fps
Found match, group 13:  30 tbr

Comment: The matching multiple occurrences also work great but there's one last thing...It only gets the video..it doesn't match the audio lines

Comment: Can you please edit it so that it matches the Stream #0:1: Audio: also? The numbers 0:1 may change so please just make it match that stream#x:x: format.

Comment: yes that's great but is it possible to have a combination because here it only gets the audio but not the video details

Comment: It's missing one value and that is the yuv420p. I would really appreciate if you could advise me on how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the info for both video and audio in seperate variables and array.

`const regex = /^(?:.|\n)*Video\:\s(\w+\d+)\s\(([\w\s]+)\).*\,\s([\w\d]+)\(([\w\s]+)\)\,\s{1}(\d+x\d+)[,\s]+(\d{0,4}\sfps)\,\s(\d+\stbr)\,\s(\d+k\stbn)\,\s(\d+\stbc)\s+.*Audio\:\s(.*)\,\s(\d+\s\w+)$/`

Here is the link for testing : https://regex101.com/r/0gEsnN/2

Here is the code :

```js
const regex = /^(?:.|\n)*Video\:\s(\w+\d+)\s\(([\w\s]+)\).*\,\s([\w\d]+)\(([\w\s]+)\)\,\s{1}(\d+x\d+)[,\s]+(\d{0,4}\sfps)\,\s(\d+\stbr)\,\s(\d+k\stbn)\,\s(\d+\stbc)\s+.*Audio\:\s(.*)\,\s(\d+\s\w+)$/;

const input = `Input #0, mpegts, from 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3456':
      Duration: N/A, start: 1809.522000, bitrate: N/A
      Program 256
        Metadata:
          service_name    : AIR_CH_521_6M
          service_provider: ITE
        Stream #0:0[0x7d1]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
        Stream #0:1[0x7d2]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels`;

const resultArr = input.match(regex);

const values = resultArr.slice(1);
console.log("Values : ", values);

const [,vC1,vC2, vC3,vC4, vRes, vFps, vTbr, vTbn, vTbc, aCodec, aChannels] = resultArr;
console.log("vC1 : ", vC1);
console.log("vC2 : ", vC2);
console.log("vC3 : ", vC3);
console.log("vC4 : ", vC4);
console.log("vRes : ", vRes);
console.log("vFps : ", vFps);
console.log("vTbr : ", vTbr);
console.log("vTbn : ", vTbn);
console.log("vTbc : ", vTbc);
console.log("aCodec : ", aCodec);
console.log("aChannels : ", aChannels);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do you know how I can further split these values h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive) into ['h264','Constrained Baseline'],['yuv420p',progressive'] ?

Comment: @josh updated the answer. It'll be now available in the array itself.

Comment: Thank you.. now I tried the same regex for another video using ffmpeg but it's not getting the details...I've updated it here : https://regex101.com/r/Vyq5kD/2 .